# Get WP-API v2 using oauth2 instead of oauth1.0a

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0, wp-api

I know that the v2.wp-api.org uses the OAUTH-Server plugin to work with oauth1.0a
Is there a maintained way to get it working with oauth2?

Comment: I would like to see this as well.